# Reviewing "Suggested Edits" with less than 2000 points?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

When I look at the review queue for "Suggested Edits", it tells me that

> You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits.

But I saw a user with 300-400 reputation reviewed Suggested Edits.
How is this possible?

Comment: Link, or it didn't happen. Please share with us where you saw this.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the above comments means where did you see a user review suggested edits when they have 300-400 rep, not where you saw the message.

Comment: It's possible to review a suggested edit with less than 2k rep _but_ only if you're the "owner" of the post that the edit was suggested on.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/2278/custodian) search for [user rubrin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2111802/rubrin). A user with a rep of 1, created the account 2 days ago, already reviewed?! Update: [Better link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2111802/rubrin?tab=activity&sort=reviews). And ben is right in that this one reviewed a suggested edit on his own post.

Comment: @cfi As the comments above state... it's their own post. The owner may cast a binding vote to accept or reject. And you know you can link straight to the edit-suggestion, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1616040 . look at this. the user has only 10 reputation.