# Cannot review suggested edits but I have reviewed one

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Well, in SO I cannot access the review suggested edits, as I do not have 2k reputation. But I seem to have reviewed one in the past (which I do not remember at all).

[image: See it here]

My guess is that maybe it was a suggested edit in a post I made (a question I asked), and I accepted the edit. That is what I think from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169336/reviewing-suggested-edits-with-less-than-2000-points).

A user commented:

> It's possible to review a suggested edit with less than 2k rep but
>   only if you're the "owner" of the post that the edit was suggested on

Is that true then? I have searched for the questions I have asked (quite some), and all are edited by me (typical thing you forget to format something or whatever). So I cannot seem to find anything... It is just mere curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19128850) was your first review action, as can be seen in [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7396613/m-k?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=14):

> [image]

Comment: Wow that was fast! Okay thanks a lot! I did not know I could see that in the "activity" page! I'll mark it as answer in 10 mins!

Comment: Cheers, and yeah the profile page is a real gold mine... ;-)